# incrementing value of column value with updateAll()

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-cactiverecord, cactiverecord

This works very well:

```
   $test = self::updateAll(
                        array( 'left_nr' => '3',
                               'right_nr' => '3', ),
                        'left_nr>=:left_nr AND right_nr>=:right_nr',
                        array(
                            ':left_nr' => $parent->left_nr,
                            ':right_nr' => $parent->right_nr,
                            //':new_left_nr' => 'left_nr + 2',
                            //':new_right_nr' => 'right_nr + 2'

                        )
                    );
```

but what I want is:

```
   $test = self::updateAll(
                        array( 'left_nr' => ':new_left_nr',
                               'right_nr' => ':new_right_nr', ),
                        'left_nr>=:left_nr AND right_nr>=:right_nr',
                        array(
                            ':left_nr' => $parent->left_nr,
                            ':right_nr' => $parent->right_nr,
                            ':new_left_nr' => 'left_nr + 2',
                           ':new_right_nr' => 'right_nr + 2'

                        )
                    );
```

When I try that code, I get following error:

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `test_nested_set` SET `left_nr`=:yp0, `right_nr`=:yp1 WHERE left_nr>=:left_nr AND right_nr>=:right_nr

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong, you can achieve this goal with something like `updateCounters()` like below:

```
<?php

$test = self::model()->updateCounters(
    array(
        'left_nr' => 2, // this is equal to => left_nr = left_nr+2
        'right_nr' => 2
    ), 
    'left_nr >= :left_nr AND right_nr >= :right_nr',
    array(
        ":left_nr" => $parent->left_nr,
        ":right_nr" => $parent->right_nr,
    )
);

?>
```

Yii defines `UpdateCounters()` :

> Updates one or several counter columns. Note, this updates all rows of data unless a condition or criteria is specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this

```
User::model()->updateAll(array(
    'field_name'=> new CDbExpression('field_name + 1')),
    "u_id = 10"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

At Yii2

Place this on top of your controller:

```
use yii\db\Expression;
```

At your action you can update a calculated column as follows:

```
Testlog::updateAll(['duration' => new Expression('duration + (5*60)')], 
                   ['testlogid' => $tid]);
```

The above produces the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `testlog` SET `duration`=duration + (5*60) WHERE `testlogid`='15'
```